# React class component doesnt see div inside render()

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a class component and I'm wondering what is wrong with that code that it doesn't recognize `div`.

```
import React from "react";
import { toggleMark } from "prosemirror-commands";
import { TextSelection } from "prosemirror-state";
import { Decoration, DecorationSet } from "prosemirror-view";
import { _t } from "../../helpers/strings";
export class LinkEditorr extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div> Hi </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more? What do you mean by "doesn't recognize?" Did you get an error message?

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in it. Please reproduce the problem on codesandbox

Comment: Here is the code, why there are errors for render() method? https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-wiles-rclngg?file=/src/App.ts

Comment: `Cannot find name div`...

Comment: Do you use `create-react-app`? It could be a problem in configuration do you use .jsx or .js?

Comment: Hi, @Mercer, you should use jsx or tsx file extension, but not ts or js.

Comment: @Mercer, this is my codesandbox  - https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-dust-xkwqdj?file=/src/App.tsx.